# Session management in JAX-WS

Tags: java, session, jax-ws

Is it possible a secured session management in methods of a web service and methods of different web services on same application? If I create a session in a method of a web service, how to get session from another method of same web service or different web service?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this post will be useful for you:
 http://it.spsu.edu/research/Tech_Report/Kai_1.pdf

Regards,

Andre.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to pass a cookie into every method in the webService.